# Does snmpd support SNMP monitoring of SendMail queues?

Tags: linux, centos, smtp, sendmail, snmp

CentOS 5.7 | SendMail 8.14.x

I've got a CentOS box running snmpd and I'd like to monitor sendmail queues. Is this natively supported by snmpd or will I need to do something special to monitor it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does appear this has been done as there is a mib for sendmail.  I found [this reference](http://tutorialsparadise.blogspot.com/2010/03/monitoring-sendmail-mail-queue-with.html) to implementation and several references to using mibII/mta_sendmail.c

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what I needed.  Worked like a charm.